# How to change image in UIimage view from counter

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uiimageview

really struggling on how I would change the image every 2 minutes based on the counter/ timer I have created. I would like the UIImage view to display an image for 2 minutes and then switch to another image, then another image , then another image, based off my counter. Here is the counter code.

```
@objc func runTimer() {
    counter += 0.1
    // HH:MM:SS:
    let flooredCounter = Int(floor(counter))
    let hour = flooredCounter / 3600
    let minute = (flooredCounter % 3600) / 60
    var minuteString = "\(minute)"
    if minute < 10 {
        minuteString = "0\(minute)"
    }
    let second = (flooredCounter % 3600) % 60
    var secondString = "\(second)"
    if second < 10 {
        secondString = "0\(second)"
    }
    _ = String(format: "%.1f", counter).components(separatedBy: ".").last!

    timerLabel.text = "\(hour):\(minuteString):\(secondString)"
```

here is the start, pause and reset buttons

```
@IBAction func startWorkingAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    if !isTimerRunning {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        isTimerRunning = true

        resetButton.isEnabled = false
        resetButton.alpha = 0.2

        pauseButton.isEnabled = true
        pauseButton.alpha = 1.0

        startWorkingButton.isEnabled = false
        startWorkingButton.alpha = 0.2

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519)
    }

}
@IBAction func pauseAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    resetButton.isEnabled = true
    resetButton.alpha = 1.0

    startWorkingButton.isEnabled = true
    startWorkingButton.alpha = 1.0

    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    pauseButton.alpha = 0.2

    isTimerRunning = false
    timer.invalidate()

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)
}
@IBAction func resetAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    timer.invalidate()
    isTimerRunning = false
    counter = 0.0

    timerLabel.text = "0:00:00"

    resetButton.isEnabled = false
    resetButton.alpha = 0.0

    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    pauseButton.alpha = 0.0

    startWorkingButton.isEnabled = true
    startWorkingButton.alpha = 1.0

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)

}
```

and the outlet for the uiimage is

```
  @IBOutlet weak var treeGrow: UIImageView!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to solve. This is how I use it inside my app:

```
//MARK: ImagePreviewAnimation

// timer for imagePreview
    var timer: Timer?
    var currentImage: UIImage?
    var currentImageIndex = 0

    func startImagePreviewAnimation(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.6, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func timerAction(){
        currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % Constants.ImageList.images.count
        UIView.transition(with: self.imagePreview, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.imagePreview.image = Constants.ImageList.images[self.currentImageIndex]
            self.currentImage = self.imagePreview.image
        })
    }
```

This changes the image every `1.6` seconds with a soft transition. An important thing to know is that you should call `timer.invalidate()` if you go to another `ViewController`.

`Constants.ImageList` is my simply the list that contains all the images. With the trick of calling `%` the list always restarts when reaching the end.